# How to exclude packages for updating in R?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I want to keep some packages downloaded from CRAN/Bioconductor in the older version while I could update other packages using commands like `biocLite()` .

How could I make a black list and tell R not to update specific packages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prepare an "updatable" list of packages, then call `biocLite`

```
blacklist <- c("pkga", "pkgb")
installed <- rownames(installed.packages())
updatable <- installed[!installed %in% blacklist]
biocLite(updatable)
```

Comment: slight improvement: updatable <- setdiff(installed, blacklist)

Comment: biocLite is not available, using BiocManager::install(updatable) instead.